# Is it possible to receive federal Pell Grant payments retroactively for prior unclaimed semesters?

Tags: funding, education

I recently became aware that I'm eligible to receive federal Pell Grant aid for my education expenses. I was unaware of my eligibility in the past. While reading some Pell Grant information, I came across this excerpt concerning retroactive payments:

> The school can pay a student retroactively for any completed
>   payment periods within the award year if the student was eligible for
>   payment in those periods. Thus, if the school receives a valid output
>   document for the student while he or she is enrolled as an eligible
>   student in the summer term, but the student was also enrolled and
>   eligible for payment in the previous fall term, that student must be paid retroactively for the fall term.

Link to the source pdf file: https://ifap.ed.gov/sfahandbooks/attachments/0304Vol3Ch4.pdf

I don't fully understand its meaning. Can anyone clarify whether I might be able to claim the previous Fall 2015 and Spring 2016 Pell Grant funding retroactively, or perhaps back even further? (I could provide appropriate documentation to show eligibility for those periods)

Comment: Pell grants are a form of financial aid for undergraduate students in the US.  Thus this is off-topic.  In any case, it would be appropriate to ask your school's financial aid office this question.

Comment: @brianborchers "... unless they can also apply to graduate or poat-graduate students as well." I would say that finding out retroactive claims are valid, certainly counts as such. Especially if you're scraping funds for your M(field) or PhD and only just found out this information.

Comment: Technically this can also apply to a specific post-baccalaureate program, but do what you must.

Comment: The PDF provided cites the statute about retroactive payments: http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&SID=ef04139925ea1e66b7643da86267e779&rgn=div8&view=text&node=34:4.1.1.1.5.5.1.4&idno=34 It is possible you can get a payment you missed during the award year, but it is relatively unlikely you'll get it farther back than that. You will need to check with your institution to confirm this, and statutes indicate a combination of "can" and "must" - so there is some discretion given to the institution, as well as some federal regulations in play. See what they say first.